# Visual basic 2010, database – how to fill specific field

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, ms-access-2010, database-connection

I'm creating database connection in Visual Basic. When user click on "borrow book" it transfer chosen data into table used for lent books. It all works alright, but I need last thing. In my database in lent table I have attribute "End date of lent" and I want fill it everytime when user borrow a book with date today + 1 month (for instance, if now is 19/04/2016, end date will be 19/05/2016). I created method "BorrowTime" for this, but I don't know what I should type into and how can I get value of inserted row into "row". And sorry for horrible look of code and form...

```
Public Class frm_UserView
    Dim BooksSource As New BindingSource
    Dim BorrowSource As New BindingSource

    Dim BooksView As New DataView
    Dim BorrowView As New DataView

    Dim ds As New DataSet

    Dim Borrow As Byte


    Private Sub frm_UserView_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        tmr_Timer.Start()
        Me.LoanerBooksTableAdapter.Fill(Me.GMITLibraryDataSet1.LoanerBooks)
        Me.BooksTableAdapter.Fill(Me.GMITLibraryDataSet.Books)

        BooksSource = dgd_UserBookView.DataSource
        BooksView = CType(BooksSource.List, DataView)

        ds = BooksView.DataViewManager.DataSet.Clone

        BorrowSource.DataSource = ds
        BorrowSource.DataMember = "Books"

        BorrowView = CType(BorrowSource.List, DataView)
        dgd_User_Borrow_View.DataSource = BorrowSource



    End Sub

    Private Sub btn_Borrow_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_BorrowBook.Click
        Borrow = 1
        MoveBooks(dgd_UserBookView, BorrowView, Borrow)

        dgd_User_Borrow_View.Sort(dgd_User_Borrow_View.Columns(0), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)

        BorrowSource.MoveLast()
        BorrowSource.MoveLast()
    End Sub
    Private Sub MoveBooks(ByRef source As DataGridView, ByRef target As DataView, ByRef borrow As Byte)
        For i = 0 To source.SelectedRows.Count - 1
            Dim numberOfRow As Integer
            Dim row As DataRowView
            row = target.AddNew()
            Dim col As Int16 = 0
            For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In source.SelectedRows(i).Cells
                row.Item(col) = cell.Value
                If borrow = 1 Then
                    numberOfRow = 0
                    BorrowTime(numberOfRow, dgd_User_Borrow_View)
                End If
                col = col + 1
            Next
        Next

        Dim count As Int16 = source.SelectedRows.Count

        For i = 0 To count - 1
            source.Rows.RemoveAt(source.SelectedRows(0).Index)
        Next
    End Sub
    Private Sub BorrowTime(ByRef row As Integer, ByRef dgd_Table As DataGridView)
        'Code for adding date
    End Sub

    Private Sub btn_ReturnBook_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_ReturnBook.Click
        Borrow = 0
        MoveBooks(dgd_User_Borrow_View, BooksView, Borrow)

        dgd_UserBookView.Sort(dgd_UserBookView.Columns(0), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)

        BooksSource.MoveLast()
        BooksSource.MoveLast()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btn_UserLogOut_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_UserLogOut.Click
        frm_Login.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmr_Timer.Tick
        Dim countBooks As Integer
        Dim countLent As Integer
        countBooks = BooksSource.Count
        countLent = BorrowSource.Count

        lbl_BookCounter.Text = "There are " + countBooks.ToString + " books"
        lbl_BorrowCounter.Text = "You have lent " + countLent.ToString + " books"
    End Sub
End Class
```

I need to put code here:

```
 Private Sub BorrowTime(ByRef row As Integer, ByRef dgd_Table As DataGridView)
       'Code for adding date
 End Sub
```

My form

[image]

Comment: I need to have it today, please help

Answer (score 0):

Public Class frm_UserView
    Dim BooksSource As New BindingSource
    Dim BorrowSource As New BindingSource

```
Dim BooksView As New DataView
Dim BorrowView As New DataView

Dim ds As New DataSet

Dim Borrow As Byte


Private Sub frm_UserView_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    tmr_Timer.Start()
    Me.LoanerBooksTableAdapter.Fill(Me.GMITLibraryDataSet1.LoanerBooks)
    Me.BooksTableAdapter.Fill(Me.GMITLibraryDataSet.Books)

    BooksSource = dgd_UserBookView.DataSource
    BooksView = CType(BooksSource.List, DataView)

    ds = BooksView.DataViewManager.DataSet.Clone

    BorrowSource.DataSource = ds
    BorrowSource.DataMember = "Books"

    BorrowView = CType(BorrowSource.List, DataView)
    dgd_User_Borrow_View.DataSource = BorrowSource



End Sub

Private Sub btn_Borrow_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_BorrowBook.Click
    Borrow = 1
    MoveBooks(dgd_UserBookView, BorrowView, Borrow)

    dgd_User_Borrow_View.Sort(dgd_User_Borrow_View.Columns(0), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)

    BorrowSource.MoveLast()
    BorrowSource.MoveLast()
End Sub
Private Sub MoveBooks(ByRef source As DataGridView, ByRef target As DataView, ByRef borrow As Byte)
    For i = 0 To source.SelectedRows.Count - 1
        Dim numberOfRow As Integer
        Dim row As DataRowView
        row = target.AddNew()
        Dim col As Int16 = 0
        For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In source.SelectedRows(i).Cells
            row.Item(col) = cell.Value
            If borrow = 1 Then
                numberOfRow = 0
                BorrowTime(numberOfRow, dgd_User_Borrow_View)
            End If
            col = col + 1
        Next
    Next

    Dim count As Int16 = source.SelectedRows.Count

    For i = 0 To count - 1
        source.Rows.RemoveAt(source.SelectedRows(0).Index)
    Next
End Sub
Private Sub BorrowTime(ByRef row As Integer, ByRef dgd_Table As DataGridView)
    'Code for adding date
End Sub

Private Sub btn_ReturnBook_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_ReturnBook.Click
    Borrow = 0
    MoveBooks(dgd_User_Borrow_View, BooksView, Borrow)

    dgd_UserBookView.Sort(dgd_UserBookView.Columns(0), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)

    BooksSource.MoveLast()
    BooksSource.MoveLast()
End Sub

Private Sub btn_UserLogOut_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_UserLogOut.Click
    frm_Login.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmr_Timer.Tick
    Dim countBooks As Integer
    Dim countLent As Integer
    countBooks = BooksSource.Count
    countLent = BorrowSource.Count

    lbl_BookCounter.Text = "There are " + countBooks.ToString + " books"
    lbl_BorrowCounter.Text = "You have lent " + countLent.ToString + " books"
End Sub
```

End Class